# IE Problem CCS div on Drupal site

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drupal

I made a Drupal site that runs without problems in all browsers except for IE. The whole 'main content' div breaks out off the stucture (goes over the edges of both the div that centers the site as well as the footer).

To be honest it's my first Drupal site that I themed myself. I used a Dreamweaver template to start with but changed it along the way (checking it only in other browsers).

I tried to modify it for IE but got stuck. You can see the mess on www.chocolatemonggo.com (The problem occurs on all pages but the homepage)
The css for the contentdiv is as follows:

```
.thrColFixHdr #mainContent {
    clear: right;
    color:#52351a;
    width:750px;
    left: 260px;
    padding: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #2c1912 0px 2px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #2c1912 0px 2px 3px;
    box-shadow: #2c1912 0px 2px 3px;
    background-color: #ccb89d;
    background-image: url(images/background_content.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

I have a footer (that shows just a background image) and footer underneath that div that shows some links (in a drupal block).
I talked to several people already, nobody could help really out. I hope some one out there can help me out.Thank you so much!

Comment: please specify which versions of IE you're having trouble with. It makes a *big* difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your width is too large. Try 715px.

You may want to wrap that in conditional css tags on all but the homepage.

Comment: I'll try that, see how that goes.

Comment: I viewed on of the product pages (just a random link I followed) and opened up [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Debug) to play with the values. Reducing the width got it fitting nicely.

Comment: Hey Dickie. In the meantime I changed back to an older CSS version (with other problems...) That's why that part is looking okay now. But please click on a product in the productspage and see how the maincontent all of a sudden goes under the navigation structure

Comment: For page 'http://www.chocolatemonggo.com/products_bars', using ie.css, change '.thrColFixHdr #mainContent' width to 'auto' and margin to '0 10px 10px 220px'. And padding-right:0px;

Comment: Hi Dickie, it still goes under the sidebar. I believe it is because it is a view (most of the other pages are 'pages' with views in blocks). I will come back to this problem, but unfortunately I have go now. Thanks for your efforts I hope to get your help in the future.